# I want to run my script in mySQL, but it keep showing this while I run it!!! ERROR 1215 (HY000) at line 18: Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, spring-data-jpa

below is my code, please have a look and help me point out the solution. i'm try to create database and use for my spring boot project.

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS recipeDb;
CREATE DATABASE recipeDb;

USE recipeDb;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS recipe;
CREATE TABLE recipe (
id int NOT NULL,
recipeTitle varchar(30),
description varchar(255),
cookTime int,
ingredientID int,
stepID int,

PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

ALTER TABLE recipe
ADD FOREIGN KEY (ingredientID) REFERENCES ingredient(id);
ADD FOREIGN KEY (stepID) REFERENCES step(id);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS category;
CREATE TABLE category (
id int NOT NULL,
categoryTitle varchar(20),

PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS recipe_category;
CREATE TABLE recipe_category (
recipeID int,
categoryID int
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS step;
CREATE TABLE step (
id int NOT NULL,
stepDesctiption varchar(255),

PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ingredient;
CREATE TABLE ingredient (
id int NOT NULL,
ingredientName varchar(255),

PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try moving your alter table to the bottom of your code

```
ALTER TABLE recipe
ADD FOREIGN KEY (ingredientID) REFERENCES ingredient(id),
ADD FOREIGN KEY (stepID) REFERENCES step(id),
```

**EDIT**

how about trying to add the foreign key in your `CREATE TABLE`. Move it also to the bottom of your code.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS recipe;
CREATE TABLE recipe (
id int NOT NULL,
recipeTitle varchar(30),
description varchar(255),
cookTime int,
ingredientID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES ingredient(id),
stepID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES step(id),

PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Comment: I try follow the instruction you given, and the system give me this error ->>ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 51: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ADD FOREIGN KEY (stepID) REFERENCES step(id)' at line 1
Operation failed with exitcode 1.      what should i do next?

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks. it is work, i should change ADD FOREIGN KEY (ingredientID) REFERENCES ingredient(id); to become ADD FOREIGN KEY (ingredientID) REFERENCES ingredient(id),

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add a foreign key that references a table that does not exist yet.

You need to put the CREATE TABLE's for the referenced tables first. Or alternately you leave adding the foreign keys to the end of the script.

Comment: I try to alter the table at the end of script, but the system give me this error ->>ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 51: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ADD FOREIGN KEY (stepID) REFERENCES step(id)' at line 1
Operation failed with exitcode 1.      what should i do next?